# Sails Js POST request

Tags: javascript, express, sails.js

I have a html form that makes a POST request to `/upload/upld` in my sails app. My aim is to have two parameters: a photo to be uploaded and the location where the photo was taken. My upload controller is supposed to upload the file to a directory with the value of the location parameter.

```
      <form method="post" action="/upload/upld" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file wow bounceIn top-buffer">
          Browse <input type="file" name="photo">
          <input type="hidden" name="location" value="istana" />
        </span>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary wow bounceIn top-buffer">
      </form>
```

Unfortunately this code does not seem to be working. The output on console shows the following whenever I upload just a single file. I'm not sure why the upld method seems to run twice on a single upload.

```
{ location: 'istana', id: undefined }
istana
{ id: undefined }
undefined
```

My upload controller looks like this:

```
    upld: function (req, res) {
            var params = req.params.all();
            console.log(params);
            var this_location = params.location;
            console.log(this_location);
            req.file('photo').upload({ dirname:require('path').join('./',this_location)},function (err, files) {
                    if (err){
                            return res.serverError(err);
                    }
                    return res.view('homepage',{

                                    message: files.length + ' file(s) uploaded successfully!',
                                    files: files
                            }
                    );
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was in how I structured my form. Due to the way Sails uses [Skipper](https://github.com/balderdashy/skipper) to handle `multipart/form-data`, I had to move the file input after my hidden text field.